# Setting multiple date variables - issue with vars being overridden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I program mostly backend Ruby code and am trying to do some front end JS work that i'm really not familiar with.

I'm basically trying to pre-fill a number of fields with international dates based on a master UK date. Each international date is determined with a simple addition or subtraction of a few days.

Here's a short version of what I have done. Line by line it works fine in chrome console but for some reason when setting the date on each country variable, they seem to be carried fwd and influence the next one. I don't understand what's happening as surely the independently named vars should be able to be altered independently? I've added the console.log output with a comment on each.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#gb_date').change(function() {

    //Grab GB date
    gb = new Date($('#gb_date').val());
      console.log(gb) // Mon Mar 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) : This is correct and as expected

    // Initially set territory dates vars to equal the gb date
    var ie = gb;
    var de = gb;

    // Then calculate and set territory dates by adding or subtracting days
    ie.setDate(ie.getDate() - 3); //Friday before
      console.log(ie); // Fri Feb 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT) : Again as expected
    de.setDate(de.getDate() + 4); //Friday after
      console.log(ie); // Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 : Why has ie been reset here??
      console.log(de); // Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 : Why is this being set based off the ie value and not the de var set above??

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `ie`,`de`, and `gb` are all the same object so you are setting and getting from the same object. You need to make each one have their own separate Date object

```
//Create new Date objects based off the old one.
var ie = new Date(gb);
var de = new Date(gb);

ie.setDate(ie.getDate() - 3);
de.setDate(de.getDate() + 4);
```

Comment: Ah, so it's not just copying the value to the new variable. That makes some sense. I think I prefer your first suggestion as it's more intuitive. Thanks!